# Angular 4, <md-checkbox> no two-way binding

Tags: angular, checkbox

I have a checkbox  in HTML as below and want to have two-way binding with an variable in ts:

```
...
        </md-grid-tile>
        <md-grid-tile class="grid-box-row"> 
            <md-checkbox ng-model="item.exportable">{{item.exportable}}
            </md-checkbox>
        </md-grid-tile>        
    </div>
    </ng-container>
</md-grid-list>
```

item.exportable is a boolean defined in ts:

```
exportable: boolean;
```

it is shown like this:
[image]

it's not checked even if the value is true. And click on the checkbox on UI doesn't affect the value displayed after the checkbox. Pleaes help. Thanks.

---

Thank you all for your responses.
After adding square bracket and parentheses pair:

```
       </md-grid-tile>
        <md-grid-tile class="grid-box-row"> 
            <md-checkbox [(ng-model)]="item.exportable">{{item.exportable}}
            </md-checkbox>
        </md-grid-tile>        
    </div>
    </ng-container>
</md-grid-list>
```

I got this error:

```
Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'ng-model' since it isn't a known property of 'md-checkbox'.
1. If 'md-checkbox' is an Angular component and it has 'ng-model' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'md-checkbox' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("
        </md-grid-tile>
        <md-grid-tile class="grid-box-row"> 
            <md-checkbox [ERROR ->][(ng-model)]="item.exportable">{{item.exportable}}
            </md-checkbox>
        </md-grid-til
```

I have FormsModule imported in app.module.ts:

```
import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
```

...

```
imports: [...
FormsModule,
```

And I also added FormsModule into the component.ts:

```
import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
```

Anything I need from '@angular/material'?

Comment: Make sure that `exportable` isn't just a variable as is. If you want to use `item.exportable` you shouldn't use variable `exportable`, they are not the same. Also as mentioned, use `[(ngModel)]`, `ng-model` is **AngularJS** syntax! https://plnkr.co/edit/Xg9FvEW9TVwRk1YRIOJq?p=preview

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve this **material** way without using **ngModel**

isChecked = true;

```
<md-checkbox
          class="example-margin"
          [checked]="isChecked"
          [indeterminate]="indeterminate"
          [align]="align"
          (change)="isChecked = !isChecked"
          [disabled]="disabled">
        I'm a checkbox
      </md-checkbox>
```

plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/xCpLFKzQnur9Si2KECiW?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

There is no more `ng-model` in Angular. You can either capture the `click` event, use the `ReactiveForms` module, or use the updated syntax:

```
<md-checkbox [(ngModel)]="item.exportable">
```

in order to use `ngModel`, you'll need to import the `FormsModule`.